# Speed of pushing docker containers extremely low

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services

I have a problem with pushing docker to the registry.

A few weeks ago everything was okay, but now it takes a lot of time.

For example, pushing one new layer (because all other layers were pushed before and don't change) takes nearly 12 hours!!!! This is a very big amount of time if take into account that this layer weighs 3.443GB of memory at all. Firstly I think that problem was at the registry (I use Amazon ECR) but with pushing to the Docker Hub situation didn't change.

I have already updated docker engine and even aws-client and tried another PC (with other network!), but the result is the same - the speed is very low.

Could anybody help? Did you meet the problem of pushing the docker containers? I didn't find any useful tips at the Internet for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of testing and searching I found that problem was with my internet provider.